# How to place the div's in a matrix form / grid form like structure

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am creating 100's of rectangular div and now i need to place them in a grid like structure with 10 col and 10 rows. How can i do that. One important thing is that the top, bottom, left or right css style would have to be in % as I am having an imp functionality of zoom in and out and if I change the style from % to any other style as in px or em, the divs get overlapped. Is there a way to do this. When I am trying, the divs are getting place one below the other. Here it is what I have done

```
            setCss = function($divId,$len) {
            //$len specifies the count number of the particualr div  
            //  $divId = $("#window3");
                alert("xmlLength is :"+$len);
                alert("set CSS::"+$divId);
                if ($len<3)//(i%2==0)
                {
                    var size = 10;

                    $("div#"+$divId).css("top",size*$len+"%");
                    $("div#"+$divId).css("left",size*$len+"%");
                    $("div#"+$divId).css("transform","none");
                    $("div#"+$divId).css("margin","10px");

                }
                if (i>=3 )
                {
                    var size = 10;
                    $("div#"+$divId).css("top",size*$len+"%");
                    $("div#"+$divId).css("left",size*$len+"%");
                    $("div#"+$divId).css("bottom",size*$len+"%");
                    $("div#"+$divId).css("right",size*$len+"%");

                    $("div#"+$divId).css("transform","none");
                    $("div#"+$divId).css("margin","10px");

                }
            //  top:10%;left:20%;transform:none;margin:10px
                /*
                        Define the CSS for creating the grid like structure for 100 small divs
                */
            };
```

I have had tried diff combination, but none of them worked.
Any pointers could be of great help. Thanks!

Comment: when it looks like the code you posted then i can't work at all. what is 'i'? please post your entire code for that problem. Including html, css, js.

Comment: sorry, i is the count of the div or the number of that div, as in 1, 2, 3,...,99,100

Comment: But there is nothing that defines the index of the div. As far as I can see it from what you have posted, you call this function without any relation to the index. 'i' should be a parameter of the function.

Comment: @SvenBieder: i is the global variable. I updated the code now with the $len, the parameter which specified the index of the div.

Comment: in what ranges are the values for '$len'?

Comment: your whole principle is kind of strange, with the way you set the position. What you build there is not a grid, it lays the divs over each other

Comment: @SvenBieder There is no range, $len is just the index number of div that is getting created. So if basically, the input to the functions is the div name and its index say 15. Now I want to place this divs as in row col format. I know the above code is completely wrong. I did few tries as if the number is odd place left: style should be far but it didnt work.

Comment: @SvenBieder: Is there a way to put the divs in row col format, but in css the top, bottom, left and right style should be in %

Comment: let me tell you what you formulas are doing. for the first 4 divs, every new div is positioned at the bottom right of the one before. and all other divs are in the middle of your container over each other and get step by step smaller. And it makes no sense to have more than an index of 4. as soon as the index reaches 5 the size of the div is <=0.

Comment: if you have defined sizes of the container div, just keep the position of all grid divs static and float them.

Comment: @SvenBieder: yes so how should i avoid it or how should i place them. I tried other way as to have place 1st 10 divs next to each other. When the div index reaches to count 11, increase the top and reset the left to the start value. But that as well did not worked for me

Comment: If your code gets applied in a loop to hundreds of elements, it's going to be very slow. Look up the element once, not 10 times. If you don't need jQuery, use regular javascript calls like `document.getElementById`. Calculate `size*$len` once, not 6 times. If you do use jQuery, combine all your `.css` calls into 1.

Comment: as i said, if there is no real reason that a absolute position is needed keep them static and float them left. as soon as a row is full, the divs start being rendered in the next row one next to each other

Comment: and only for making this kind of simple grid it is absolutely not needed to use javascript at all. you can do it with css

Comment: @SvenBieder: can you show me a small fiddle with css. As well, i am creating the setCSS function as soon as div is created.

Comment: here is the link: http://jsfiddle.net/Ev3mW/ - I have created the grid divs with javascript, because I was too lazy to put them all in the html

Comment: @SvenBieder:It idea helped me. I change the css. Earlier i have not used the float at all and the position was style to absolute. I change the style, float to left and position as relative. I did got the grid like structure as desired. Thanks a lot for the help

Answer (score 1):

If you want cols and rows you can:

- Create a table
- Set `display:inline-block` to the divs, and each 10 add an empty extra div with `display:block`
- Set `float-left` to the divs, and each 10 add to that div `clear:right`.

With the 2nd and 3rd options you should set `min-width:[10*divWidth]` to the container.

**Edit:**

Ah, it seems you use absolute positioned divs.

Then, you can iterate through all divs with an index `i`
If `i%10 == 0`, increase the `top`property and reset `left`.

Or, even better, without needing to have a variable with the current `top` and `left`,

```
var cols=10,
    rows=5,
    wid=10,
    hei=20,
    d=document.createElement('div');
d.className='cell';
d.style.width=wid+'px';
d.style.height=hei+'px';
for(var i=0;i<cols*rows;i++){
    var c=d.cloneNode(false);
    c.style.top=Math.floor(i/cols)*hei+'px';
    c.style.left=i%cols*wid+'px';
    document.body.appendChild(c);
}
```

Here you have a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4pj74/

**Edit 2:**

If you want to create all elements first and then set their positon,

```
// Creating variables
var cols=10,
    rows=5,
    wid=10,
    hei=20,
    d=document.createElement('div'),
    wrap=document.getElementById('wrapper');
d.className='cell';
    d.style.width=wid+'px';
    d.style.height=hei+'px';

//Creating elements
for(var i=0;i<cols*rows;i++){
    var c=d.cloneNode(false);
    wrap.appendChild(c);
}

//Setting position
for(var i=0;i<wrap.childNodes.length;i++){
    setCSS(i);
}
function setCSS(i){
    var el=wrap.childNodes[i];
    el.style.top=Math.floor(i/cols)*hei+'px';
    el.style.left=i%cols*wid+'px';
}
```

(Now I append them to `<div id="wrapper"></div>` because maybe jsfiddle adds other things to the body)

See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/4pj74/3/

Comment: What if I dont want to use the table structure? What if instead of adding blank divs, I specify the margin? Can you show me a small fiddle? Thanks

Comment: Why there is a need to clone the node and append it to the body. In my case I am appending it to the body before calling the setCss function. If i remove the cloning part and appending, all the divs gets overlapped.Any way to avoid all this and get the gird like structure.